# sending sms in hebrew

Tags: sms

I'm using sms1.cardboardfish.com to sens smses through the web. I have these datacoding schemes to work with:
0: Flash
1: Normal
2: Binary
4: UCS2
5: Flash UCS2
6: Flash GSM
7: Normal GSM
and I want to send it in hebrew. right now I'm sending it in 7: Normal GSM and it comes out scrambled.. Ideas anyone?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Send it in UCS2, which is normal UTF-16 encoding.

I think this should do the trick:

```
>>> a=u"שלום"
>>> a
u'\u05e9\u05dc\u05d5\u05dd'
>>> a.encode("utf_16_be").encode("hex")
'05e905dc05d505dd'
```

Comment: Do you know how to send ucs2 hex in url?

Comment: unbelievable.. It works thanks, I tried all sorts of things and this is the simplest

Answer (score 2):

Note that when using a multi-byte character set (such as UCS2) the maximum number of characters per message will be significantly reduced. The well known 160 character limit is based on a 7 bit character set, with a 16 bit character set you'll be limited to 70 characters.

Comment: How do I convert a python string to ucs2 hex (which I need to send in url)